# How to correctly change encoding to cp866?

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.6

I'm trying to print UTF-8 and cp866 process output.

My code:

```
if "sendcmd " in message.text:
    command = message.text.replace("sendcmd ", "")
    process = os.popen(command)
    answer = process.read()
    #print(answer.decode('utf-8').encode('cp866'))
    by = bytes(answer, 'utf-8')
    print(type(by))
    print(repr(by))
    process.close()
```

after this I get that:

```
<class 'bytes'>
b'b\'\\xe2\\x80\\x9c\\xd0\\xb1\\xd0\\x87\\xd2\\x90\\xd0\\xb5: \\xd0\\x8b\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\x87\\xd0\\xb0\\xc2\\xa0\\xd1\\x9e\\xc2\\xab\\xd2\\x90\\xc2\\xad \\xd0\\xb1\\xd0\\x81\\xd0\\x88\\xc2\\xad\\xc2\\xa0\\xc2\\xab \\xc2\\xa7\\xc2\\xa0\\xd1\\x9e\\xd2\\x90\\xd0\\xb0\\xd0\\xb8\\xd2\\x90\\xc2\\xad\\xd0\\x81\\xd0\\xbf \\xd0\\x87\\xd0\\xb0\\xc2\\xae\\xd0\\xb6\\xd2\\x90\\xd0\\xb1\\xd0\\xb1\\xd0\\xb3 "whatever.exe" \\xd0\\xb1 \\xd0\\x81\\xc2\\xa4\\xd2\\x90\\xc2\\xad\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\x81\\xd0\\xb4\\xd0\\x81\\xd0\\x84\\xc2\\xa0\\xd0\\xb2\\xc2\\xae\\xd0\\xb0\\xc2\\xae\\xc2\\xac 3720.\\n\'
```

I understand that I need to change encoding to cp866, but I don't understand how to implement it =(

Update: And this code didn't help:

```
uni = type(by), repr(by)
print(uni.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Comment: wjandrea, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.popen` 's `read` method returns `str`, the the output from the process is automatically decoded. `subprocess.Popen` is similar to `os.popen` and can be customized ; it returns raw `bytes` instead of `str` text:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

if "sendcmd " in message.text:
    ...
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE)
    answer = process.communicate()[0]          # (stdout, stderr)
    print(answer.decode('cp866'))
```

Internally, `os.popen` uses the `subprocess` module, you might need to slightly change the `command` argument. Check `Popen` 's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).